# Bootstrap notifications working locally but not in server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have notifications set up in a localhost application and everything is working perfectly. I upload to the server and the notifications do not display, even though no changes have been made.

I have two files -

1. **notifications.php** which prepares the display output
2. **fetch-notifications.php** which actually checks to see if there are any notifications available, and passes through to notifications.php

I include notifications.php in relevant files and confirm this part is definitely working. When I check debugging, I can see that notifications.php is definitely calling on the correct file using the correct path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm stuck here!

**notifications.php**

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #alert_popover
    {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        right:15px;
        top:0px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .wrapper {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        height: auto;
        width:200px;
        z-index: -1;

    }

</style>

<div id="alert_popover">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        setInterval(function(){
            load_last_notification();
        }, 5000);


        function load_last_notification()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"/cl/includes/fetch-notifications.php",
                method:"POST",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('.content').html(data);
                }
            })
        }

    });
</script>
```

**fetch-notifications.php**

```
include 'db.php';
include 'security.php';

$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
$output = '';

$db = new db();
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE status = '0' AND targetUserID = '$userID'");

if ($query->numRows() > 0) {

    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE status = 0 AND targetUserID = '$userID' ORDER BY notificationID ASC LIMIT 1")->fetchAll();
    foreach ($query as $result) {

        $hasLink = $result['hasLink'];
        $popupClass = $result['popupClass'];

        if ($hasLink == 1) {
            $entity = $result['entity'];
            $entityID = $result['entityID'];

            switch ($entity) {
                case 'voyage':
                    $link = "/cl/unit/view?voyageID=$entityID";
                    break;
                case 'vessel':
                    $link = "/cl/unit/view?vesselID=$entityID";
                    break;
                case 'vesselReport':
                    $link = "/cl/unit/view/reports/view?reportID=$entityID";
                    break;
                case 'vesselReportDraft':
                    $link = "/cl/unit/view/reports/draft/view?reportID=$entityID";
                    break;
            }
        }

        $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $createTimestamp = $result['createTimestamp'];
        $minutes = (time() - strtotime($createTimestamp));

        $start_date = new DateTime($createTimestamp);
        $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($now));

        if ($since_start->days > 0) {
            $timeDisplay = $since_start->days . " days ago";
        } elseif ($since_start->h >= 1) {
            $timeDisplay = $since_start->h . " hours ago";
        } elseif ($since_start->m >= 1) {
            $timeDisplay = $since_start->m . " mins ago";
        } else {
            $timeDisplay = "Just Now";
        }

        if (empty($popupClass)) {
            $popupClass = 'info';
        }

        $output .= '
 <div class="alert alert-' . $popupClass . '">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  <p><strong>' . $result["subject"] . '</strong>
  <br>
   ' . $result["notification"] . ' <br><small><i>' . $timeDisplay . '</small></i>
  </p>';

        if ($hasLink == 1) {
            $output .= "<a href='$link'><button type='button' class='btn btn-white btn-block'>View</button></a>";
        }

        $output .= '</div>
 ';

        $notificationID = $result['notificationID'];
        $query = $db->query("UPDATE notifications SET status = '0', readTimestamp = '$now' WHERE notificationID = '$notificationID'");
        $notificationID = '';
    }
}


echo $output;
```

Comment: You have a number of references in the format of `/cl/`. If you are using relative path, please use `./cl/` (otherwise the path (/) will start from the root of your web folder in the server and may cause problems)

Answer (score 0):

For Use Ajax in server . You Should add JQUERY . in your HTML file . in head tag
For example :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar scenarios happened to me when I was developing in Windows environment and deployed in Linux environments. The common issues are,

1. Permission issues (Using your browser console, make sure the /cl/includes/fetch-notifications.php returns the data from the server)
2. Case sensitivity issues (Check all PHP variables and MySQL field names are correct. They are case sensitive in Linux environments)